# How do I use a single quote in for /F command

Tags: windows, batch-file

I want to have .bat script to check if an IIS plugin exists, here is what I tried to assign a variable with the output of command,

```
set appcmd=%WINDIR%\System32\inetsrv\appcmd.exe
set cmd_list=%appcmd% list config -section:isapiFilters /text:[path='D:\iisplugins\F5XForwardedFor.dll'].path
for /f "usebackq" %%s in (`%cmd_list%`) do set filterPath=%%s
echo %filterPath%
```

But it didn't work, the output from command prompt:

```
set filterPath=ERROR
echo ERROR
```

It seems "=" needs to be escaped, so I tried again,

```
set cmd_list=%appcmd% list config -section:isapiFilters /text:[path^='D:\iisplugins\F5XForwardedFor.dll'].path
```

It still didn't work, "^" needs also be escaped? Tried one more time,

```
set cmd_list=%appcmd% list config -section:isapiFilters /text:[path^^='D:\iisplugins\F5XForwardedFor.dll'].path
```

Still did not work. Even the single quotes were escaped. 
If executed the command alone without assigning to a variable, it worked well and returned the correct path of iis filter,

```
D:\iisplugins\F5XForwardedFor.dll
```

Comment: What's the `|` at the end of the `set` command supposed to do?

Comment: Sorry, it was typo.

Comment: What happens if you enclose the entire `/text` option in double quotes, i.e. use `"/text:[path='D:\iisplugins\F5XForwardedFor.dll'].path"`? Some applications require double quotes around the value of an option. So if first suggestion does not work, try `/text:"[path='D:\iisplugins\F5XForwardedFor.dll'].path"`. By default Windows command interpreter requires an argument string containing a space or ``&()[]{}^=;!'+,`~|<>`` to be enclosed in double quotes. But the executed application/script defines how the argument strings are processed finally and so there is no general rule for `"`...`"`.

Comment: Thanks! That does work. I have posted the correct answer below.

Comment: Please cut-and-paste code to avoid tyops. You have  mis-spelled `filterpath` in your solution - same problem.

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution, to add double quotes in the criteria,

```
set cmd_list=%appcmd% list config -section:isapiFilters /"text:[path='D:\iisplugins\F5XForwardedFor.dll'].path"
for /f "usebackq" %%s in (`%cmd_list%`) do set filterPath=%%s
echo %filterPath%
```

Instead of assigning the command result to a variable, it also does work for me to check "ERRORLEVEL".

```
%appcmd% list config -section:isapiFilter /text:[path='D:\iisplugins\F5XForwardedFor.dll'].path | findstr F5XForwardedFor
if %ERRORLEVEL% == 1 ( echo "Found" )
if %ERRORLEVEL% == 0 ( echo "Not Found")
```

Comment: Run `if /?` and read Microsoft support article [Testing for a Specific Error Level in Batch Files](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/69576). `if %ERRORLEVEL% == 1` and next IF condition work here because the two command lines are not within a command block. But better would be using `if errorlevel 1 ( echo Found ) else ( echo Not Found )` which would work also within a command block without usage of delayed environment variable expansion.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't need to make changes to a working command, just enclose it in doublequotes.

```bat
For /F "Delims=" %%A In ('"%cmd_list%"') Do Set "filterPath=%%A"
```

Full Example:

```bat
@Echo Off
Set "appcmd=%__APPDIR__%inetsrv\appcmd.exe"
Set "cmd_list="%appcmd%" list config -section:isapiFilters /text:[path='D:\iisplugins\F5XForwardedFor.dll'].path"
Set "filterPath="
For /F "Delims=" %%A In ('"%cmd_list%" 2^>Nul') Do Set "filterPath=%%A"
If Defined filterPath Echo %filterPath%
Pause
```